# These questions are all about Fourier analysis.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Please prove these equalities,these questions appear in the chapter of Fourier series. If you can use other methods,please tell me more about it, and I am glad to know how to solve the questions:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln{x}}{1-x}\mathrm dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
and
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln{x}}{1+x}\mathrm dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Expanding into series and integrating by parts:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\mathrm{d}x
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1x^k\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(k+1)^2}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{1+x}\mathrm{d}x
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\int_0^1x^k\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}
\end{align}
$$